# Will a git reset --mixed on the master branch effect my local branches?

Tags: git, github

New to git, so bear with me... and apologies for the messy visual depictions.

Here is what I thought I was doing:

```
                              -<commit>-<commit>(A)
                             /
                             -<commit>(B)
                           /
  ...-<commit 123>-(Master)
                          \
                            -<commit>-<commit>-<commit>(C)
```

But when I `git pull`'ed on `(master)` and merged, `git status` then said `your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits` (plus it doesn't work!). So I think I have:

```
                              -<mix of commits, intended for A, B or C>(A)
                             /
                             -<commits intended for B>(B)
                           /
           ...-<commit 456>-<commit>-<commit>-<commit>-<commit>-(Master)
                          \
                           -<mix of commits, intended for B or C>(C)
```

Will `git reset --mixed 456` give me this:

```
                              -<mix of commits, intended for A, B or C>(A)
                             /
                             -<commits intended for B>(B)
                           /
   ...-<commit 456>(Master)
                          \
                           -<mix of commits, intended for B or C>(C)
```

leaving A, B and C untouched?

Either way, this is what I want. How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `git status then said your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits` ... this sounds completely wrong to me.  After pulling on `master`, your local branch should have been completely in sync with the tracking branch.

Comment: I *think* the main problem here is that you *think*. You need to understand what you're doing, you need to *know* the status of your repository. In any case, if you've checked out a branch and do a git reset, you move the branch pointer. This may not be a safe operation to do. Also, the second illustration is missing your merge so it's kinda hard to tell what you merged with.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen,  @TimBiegeleisen, thanks! doing a `git log --pretty+oneline`, the commits that I'm "ahead" are not mine!... It seams I have "pulled" or whatever but my pointer is way back, with commits that aren't part of the "working code"... Did I choose the wrong option in my editor when there were conflicts? how do I get the pointer to the end?